# Google Directions API, Get Coord then show how to get to Y

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to make a website thats simply shows your location and how you get to the location where you want to go.

To get my current location im using this code i found here on stack:

```
// Get the coordinates
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);

function show_map(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // post to your controller
  var url = "/Home/Index?latitude=" + latitude + "&longtitude=" + longitude; 
  $.post(url, function(data) {
  });
}
```

I've breakpointed it and it does give me the coordinates for position.
But my problem is, how do I show how to get to point B(Point B will be hardcoded coordinates)?
I've looked into Google Directions API aswell as Distance Matrix API, and for a newbie like me the I find the documentation quite hard to understand. I'm trying to do this in an MVC 6 project, am I approaching this the wrong way? Should i keep looking at Google Directions API?

Comment: There are many examples on this website.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be performed client side via the Google Maps API and their Direction Service. Have you seen this -> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple